# Why does my LG Microwave range hood hum loudly when the fan turns on?

Tags: appliances

Lately once the microwave has been running for more than 5-10 seconds, a very loud humming noise starts happening.  When I remove the top vent panel, the humming stops, but I cannot for the life of me determine where the noise is coming from and what is causing it.

Model number LMV-1680ST

Comment: The top panel could be amplifying the fan noise, that's why you don't hear it when you remove the top.  Run the microwave until you hear the noise, then put your hand on the top.  If you feel vibrations, or the noise deadens when your hand is on it, you have found your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my range hood there was a loud hum when the fan was on, and it turned to be a metal screen that was slipping and brushing against the running fan. The fan blades scraped along the metal grill, causing the noise.

I would look inside the hood if you can, look to see where the fan is, and make sure that nothing is loose or disturbing the fan's motion. Also check that all the screws and plates are tight - loose plates can hum when they vibrate.

Answer (score 0):

It is a different model to mine, but certainly the humming mine makes is the fan - it comes on a few seconds after cooking starts, and it remains on for a minute afterwards.